# Не могу узнать высоту таблицы через jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Добрый день.

Я начинающий сайтописатель. На данный момент изучаю jQuery. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть две таблицы:

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td valign="top">
   <table width="200px" border="1" id="first_table">
    <tr>
    <td>2333<br>2 
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <table width="200px" border="1" id="second_table">
   <tr>
    <td>1
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table> с id =first_table и id=second_table.
```

Так вот нужно узнать высоту первой таблицы и присвоить эту высоту второй таблице. Делаю выборку:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var first_table_height = $('#first_table').attr('height');
    $('#forresults').text('высота первой таблицы' + first_table_height);

});
```

и он выводит у меня "высота первой таблицы - undefined". Если я поставлю вручную height первой таблицы, например, 50px, то он выводит "высота первой таблицы - 50px", а если не указывать height, то undefined. Что можно сделать, чтобы он давал значение height, при этом не указывая значение height вручную ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var f_height = $('#first_table').height(); 
var s_height = $('#second_table').height();
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 0):

[Работа с высотой элементов](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)